# Is there anything wrong with this sql?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I'm trying to insert values into my notifications table. In the PHP file, everything works perfectly fine except when I check my database in PHPmyAdmin, the values are not inserted and they are not there. Can someone please tell me if there's anything wrong with this?

```
mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO notifications(username, initiator, app, note, date_time) 
                 VALUES('$user','anonymous','$app','$note',now())");
```

Comment: You're not using prepared statements/bind vars, so are you escaping these values?

Comment: If it doesn't work, then something is likely to be wrong.  Have you checked the error message?

Comment: How do you check the error message?

Comment: Please share the error you are getting and the `create table` statement for your `notifications` table.

Comment: I don't get any errors. Everything shows and works fine but the values don't get stored in the database

Comment: I did it, now instead of showing the error it gives me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: OH yes, I got it. Thanks a lot. I found where the problems is. Thanks a lot man. I would upvote you if I could. :)

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: When I had set the variable "$note" I used double quotes instead of single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing this much code two suggestion for you:-

1. add error reporting code on top of your page just after `<?php`. Add these lines:-

   `error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);`
2. Change your query like below:-

   `mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO notifications(username, initiator, app, note, date_time) VALUES('".$user."','anonymous','".$app."','".$note."','".now()."')") or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));`

Note:- This will provide you details about what exact error occur in your code.Thanks.